# Find the volume of the following solid.

Tags: integration, volume, surface-integrals

I need to find the volume of that solid:
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3=4y^2z^2$$
I obviously tried spherical coordinates, but that simply led me to nowhere. I used:
$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos\alpha \cos\beta\\[2ex]y=r\sin\alpha \cos\beta\\[2ex]z=r\sin\beta\end{cases}$$
and it got me to the point where I have:
$$r^2=4\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\cos^2\beta.$$
and honestly I don't know what to do next.

Comment: what kind of solid is it?

Comment: I don't know, and that's the point. I only got the formula.

Comment: You are interested in the volume bounded by the surface given by your equation. Something has gone slightly wrong in your calculation. You should get something more like $r=2\sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos\beta$. The surface is four squashed spheres meeting at the origin. All have the same volume, so just find half the volume of one by integrating over $[0,\pi/2]$ for each of $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: The given equation defines a set $S\subset{\mathbb R}^3$. This set is not a "solid", but a surface (maybe with singularities).

Answer (score 1):

In spherical coordinates $(R,\theta,\phi)$ the Jacobian of the spherical coordinates is $R^2\sin\theta$. Also the equation of the surface enveloping the solid is:$$R^2=4\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi\cos^2\phi=\sin^2\theta\sin^2(2\phi)$$
For calculating the volume we have
$$\iiint_VR^2\sin\theta dR d\theta d\phi=
\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta\sin^2(2\phi)}}R^2\sin\theta dR d\phi d\theta=
\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{R^3}{3}|_{0}^{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta\sin^2(2\phi)}}\sin\theta d\phi d\theta=
\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{|\sin\theta|^3|\sin(2\phi)|^3}{3}\sin\theta d\phi d\theta$$
since $\sin\theta\ge0$ when $0\le\theta\le\pi$, the period of $|\sin(2\phi)|^3$ is $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and $\sin(2\phi)\ge0$ when $0\le\phi\le\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ we can write the integral formula as following:
$$I=4\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{\sin^4\theta}{3}\sin^3(2\phi) d\phi d\theta$$
also
 $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}4\sin^3(2\phi) d\phi=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}3\sin(2\phi)-\sin(6\phi) d\phi=\dfrac{8}{3}$$
therefore the integral can be simplified as follows:
$$I=\dfrac{8}{9}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^4\theta d\theta$$
which by substituting $\sin^2p=\dfrac{1-\cos(2p)}{2}$ gives us the final result:
$$I=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$$

[image]

Comment: clever (+1), but you shall adjust better the integral bounds for $\theta$ and $\phi$. Also put in brackets $sin(2\theta)$ etc.

Comment: You're right...I'm not very good at mathjax :)

Comment: I do not master mathjax as well, but in this case it is enough that you just put normal brackets : "\sin(2\theta)"

Comment: Would you plz do that yourself? I'm currently on my phone and can't do that