# Triple integral. Spherical coordinates. Too much calculations

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

I have troubles with integral:

$$
  \iiint \limits_{S} g(x;y;z)dxdydz\ \label{orig} \tag{1}
$$

Where $g(x;y;z) = \frac{xyz}{(a^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^3}$ and area is given by inequalities:
$$
  (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2} \leqslant 4xy, \\
  x \geqslant 0, y \geqslant 0, z\geqslant 0
$$

I know one way to solve this. I used conversion to [spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates) and got the following integral:

$$
  \int\limits_{0}^{\pi / 2}d\varphi \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}d\theta \int\limits_{0}^{\sin2\varphi(1 - \cos2\theta)} \frac{r^5 \sin2\varphi \sin2\theta(1 - \cos2\theta)}{8(a^2 + r^2)^3} dr
$$

This integral is solvable, but there are a lot of calculations in the process. My question is: *Is it possible to solve original integral $\eqref{orig}$ differently? is there more elegant solution? Maybe I'm making some mistakes?*

Comment: you can proceed along the lines given [in this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629862)

Comment: Sometimes things suck...and this seems to be one of those times.